# Visual Studio web deploy stuck in updating dll file at output console

Tags: sql, asp.net, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to publish an ASP website with a Azure SQL database to Microsoft Azure using Visual studio 2015 community. Its getting stuck at a certain point and taking too much time. Screen is shown below.

[Screenshot of Output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeDev.jpg)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the text of the screenshot. See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: Is it *"getting stuck"* or is it *"taking too much time*"?

Comment: Exactly, it's taking too much time. I'm sure that I have a good internet connection ( fibre) any idea?

Answer (score 0):

From the deployment screenshot, it seems your application takes too long time to update file CustomerCarePortal.dll. If this file is too big, it is normal to take some time to upload. If this file is not big, please try to delete this file via ftp, then deploy again to see whether it will reduce your deployment time. You could also try to deploy the application to a new clean Web APP to check whether it related with Azure Web APP environment. If you have some deployment issue, please have a look at [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/04/01/get-azure-website-deployment-logs-from-kudu/). The detailed log information may be help to find out the reason.